# ASP.NET Core API para acesso a mais de uma apicação em Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net, api, url, route

Tenho uma API que quando startada, ela sobe no seguinte endereço: **http://localhost:49013/api/values**. Percebi que isto é parametrizado no arquivo **launchSettings.json**, que está assim:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49013/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": 
  {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Cliente.IG.WebAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49012/"
    }
  }
}
```

No meu controller da API, tenho seguinte método dentro do namespace:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/IG")]
[ApiController]
public class IGController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IGResult Post([FromBody] Filtro filtro)
    {
        var app = new IgApplication();
        return app.getInstrucoes(filtro);
    }
}
```

O "IgApplication" cria uma instância da classe onde é gerado uma lista que é populada com os valores atribuidos do DAO.

Quando inicializo a aplicação "A" em angular através do localhost (http://localhost:4200/). Dentro do meu arquivo environment.prod.ts tenho a chamada:

```
    export const environment = {
  production: true,
  url: 'http://localhost:49013/'
};
```

Ela passa por esse controller e segue o fluxo e faz o que tem que ser feito.

Porém, eis a qeustão! Eu possuo a aplicação "B", que acessa a mesma API porém possui funcionalidades diferente, por isso, dentro do mesmo controller eu criei uma nova classe e um método:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Item")]
public class APIIgItemController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ItensResult Post([FromBody] Itens ValorItem)
    {
        var app = new CRUDApplication();
        return app.GetItens();
    }
}
```

Como faço para quando for startar a aplicação "B", ele passe por esse método "ItensResult" ao invés "IGResult", sendo que ambas são executadas pelo localhost:4200? Ou isso eu defino na aplicação angular? Vi que é possível configurar mais de uma "applicationUrl" dentro do json. Devo considerar essa configuração?

Desde já agradeço toda a ajuda!